# Why is there a difference between single and double compound pendulum's kinetic energy equation?

Tags: energy, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, oscillators

When calculating equation of motion of single compound pendulum, kinetic energy is taken as $K= I\dot{\theta}^2/2$ ([See](https://slideplayer.com/slide/15500109/)).

But when it is double compound pendulum, kinetic energy of the first pendulum is taken as,

$$K_1= I\dot{\theta}^2/2 + mv^2/2$$ ([See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum))  More over, kinetic energy of the single pendulum is found as $K_1$, not as $K$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000264/kinetic-energy-of-the-compound-pendulum). I am very much confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Wiki article for the double compound pendulum, the linear KEs are for the centres of mass of the pendulum and the rotational KEs are about the centres of mass.

This would also be the case for a single compound pendulum: we could write its KE as the sum of these two terms. However it is usually more convenient to write the KE as a single term: the rotational KE about the point of suspension.

Your first reference seems to be referring to a *simple* pendulum. For a simple pendulum the moment of inertia about the centre of mass (the centre of the bob) is negligible (strictly it is zero). So even if we take the KE as the sum of linear KE of C of M and rotational KE about the C of M, the latter is zero, so there is only one term.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, in first reference, you should look slider page 2, but I get what you are saying. Thank you for the answer.